# Dijkstra’s Algorithm in python

Tags: python, dijkstra

I am trying to implement Dijkstra’s algorithm on my python code but I can't really get the algorithm right. The algorithm I am using is from this youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pVfj6mxhdMw

So basically my class has these 3 variables:

```
self.nodes = [] #a,b,c
self.neighbours = {} # a:[b,c], b:[c], c:[a]
self.weights = {} #[a,b] = 2, [a,c] = 5
```

Here is how I partially implemented my shortest path function using the algorithm provided in the video:

```
def dijkstra(self, start, end):

    nodes = {}

    for n in self.nodes:
        if n == start:
                nodes[n] = 0
        else:
                nodes[n] = float('inf')

    unvisited = self.neighbours
    visited = []
    current_node = start
    current_distance = 0

    while unvisited:
        for n in unvisited[current_node]:
            print(n)
            #calc_weight = nodes[n] + self.weights[n, current_node]
            #if (unvisited[n] is None or calc_weight > nodes[n]):
                    #nodes[n] = calc_weight
        visited.append(current_node)
        del unvisited[current_node]

        if not unvisited: break
```

I havent really completed because I know I missing something out somewhere. Can someone please help me with this. Thank you

Comment: wikipedia: [Dijkstra's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm). There is even pseudocode.

Comment: Is you problem solved ?

Comment: @Shasha99 Nope. I can't seem to get that algorithm right.
The previous comments didnt help, one led me to another algorithm which isnt really an answer, while the second led me to a hello world program.

Comment: I was actually talking about this: https://code.hackerearth.com/0ed99eZ You should implement min heap for the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def dijkstra(self, start, end):

    nodes = self.neighbours #{'A': {'B':2}, 'B': {'C':4}, ... }

    unvisited = {n: 1000 for n in self.nodes} #unvisited node & distance
    unvisited[start] = 0 #set start vertex to 0
    visited = {} #list of all visited nodes
    parent = {} #predecessors

    while unvisited:
        min_node = min(unvisited, key=unvisited.get) #get smallest distance

        for neighbour in nodes[min_node].items():
            if neighbour not in visited:
                new_distance = unvisited[min_node] + nodes[min_node][neighbour]
                if new_distance < unvisited[neighbour]:
                    unvisited[neighbour] = new_distance
                    parent[neighbour] = min_node

        visited[min_node] = unvisited[min_node]
        unvisited.pop(min_node)

    print(parent, visited)
```

Comment: In order to exit the loop when the target (end) node is hit you need: `if min_node == end: break`

Comment: For undefined edges you need `nodes[min_node].get(neighbour, 1000)` instead of `nodes[min_node][neighbour]`

Comment: Also, using `float("inf")` is preferable instead of `1000`.