# Explanation of pathfinding/a* algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, path, find, a-star

Do someone want to explain me (in pseudocode too) how the pathfinding/a* algorithm can be implemented in Python? I searched all over the internet but I am not able to understand how to calculate H-cost or G-cost. I found some source code, but it is too difficult for me (I am still a newbie).

Let's think I have a map like this:

```
'''
S0000000000000000000000000100000000000
00000000000000000000100000001000000000
10000111110101000001100000001000000000
01111100010001000010100000010000000000
00000100001111100100100001110000110000
00001100000001011000000100000001000000
00000100000000101000000000011110000001
00000010000000000111111111100000000011
00000001000000000000000001100000111100
00000000110000000000000000010011000000
00000000010000000001100000001000000000
00000000010000000000110000000111111000
00000000010000000000010000000000000000
00000000011000111111111111111111111111
000000000100000110000010000000000000E0
00000000001100000100001000000000000000
00000000000100000011000000000000000000
00000000000010000000000000000000000000
'''
```

Where 1s are obstacles, 'S' is the starting point and 'E' is the end.
How can I implement that algorithm? It would be great also if you can link an internet page who explain it in a easy way.

Comment: A nice [page](https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html) with animations and stuff.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40871864/dijkstra-s-algorithm-in-python Or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22899400/4014959 ?

Comment: Thank you for the two links, now I read those pages and see!

Comment: The g-cost is the cost of the path already "walked", while the h-cost is the estimation of the remaining cost of the path to reach the goal. They are dependent on the domain you apply the a* algorithm